# How to Hide This from Woocommerce Order Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone know how to hide the Stripe fees from the Woocommerce order page in the back end. It's displayed under the total the customer pays for an item and it just repeats the total again along with the Stripe fee. It feels quite unnecessary and I was hoping a simple css code would hide it. Here is a screenshot of the part I'm trying to hide/remove: https://prnt.sc/A4VmaJ-Pxc_u

I'm not the best with CSS so the simpler the better really, thank you very much in advance.

Haven't tried anything yet, am hoping a simple CSS code will resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters to hide. Add following filters in your functions.php

```
//Hides the Stripe fee
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_hide_display_order_fee','__return_false');

//Hides the net total of the transaction without the charges of Stripe.
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_hide_display_order_payout','__return_false');
```